# How to pull a Docker image from the Azure pipeline after build a container

Tags: azure, docker, ubuntu

I have created a pipeline in Azure DevOps that builds a new container where a pull request is merged in `main`. After the build, the pipeline is pushing the new container in my Azure Container Repository. The current pipeline is as follow

```
trigger:
- main

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'xxx'
  imageRepository: 'shinyproxyimage'
  containerRegistry: 'myrepo.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/DOCKERFILE'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  
  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          latest
```

What I have to do manually after that is to login to the Ubuntu virtual machine in Azure and pull the new version of the container. I replace the last line `tags` with the word `latest` to have always the last version on this tag. By default, `tags` has value from `tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'`. Is it correct what I did?

Is it possible to add this step in the pipeline without my manual intervention?

Comment: yes, what you are looking for is deployment / release process. check this guide and amend this for your case https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/deploy-linux-vm?view=azure-devops&tabs=java

Comment: btw, is hosting the Docker container the only thing you use your VM for? if so, you might want to look at a PaaS service like Azure Container Instances or App Services for Containers instead

Comment: The process is a little bit complicated. In Azure DevOps, there are 2 pipelines for 2 services (ShinyProxy and ShinyApp). ShinyProxy is a common container that has the connections to the other ShinyApps. Basically, I'm looking for a way to run a bash script at the end of the pipeline to the Ubuntu machine to pull the new version of the container

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you, please accept it.

Comment: I found my way. I created a complete post to explain what I did https://www.puresourcecode.com/programming-languages/r/deploy-shinyapps-with-azure-and-docker/

Answer (score 1):

> I replace the last line tags with the word latest to have always the
> last version on this tag. By default, tags has value from tag:
> '$(Build.BuildId)'. Is it correct what I did?

There is no problem with your action. The default tag `tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'` is just a choice, you can use it and you can also do not use it, it depends on your requirement. You can always use the `latest` tag for the image, then there is only the `latest` tag for the image in the ACR. But it also means you can find the previous version of the image in the ACR. With only one `latest` tag, you can deploy the image with the `latest` tag without any manual changes.